# client app connects to web api local and web api hosted in azure

Tags: azure, winforms, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-signalr

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API that is hosted in azure. The Web API connects to an Azure SignalR service at startup.

Then client apps (Winforms) connects to the Web API using the Azure SignalR URL like this: `https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/myhub`.

However, when I run the Web API locally, and I try to connect my client, then the client app somehow gets connected to both the locally running Web API **AND** the Web API hosted in Azure.

I know this because the Web API has a function where it periodically sends out heartbeat to connected clients.

And my client is getting 2 of these heartbeats.

In the client app, I connect to the locally running Web API like this:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl(@"http://localhost:5000/MyHub")
    .Build();
```

How can I force my Winforms client app to only connect to the locally running Web API?

Comment: To make Winforms client app connect to only locally running Web API, 
Add the code in the if condition which runs only for Development Env.
```csharp
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()    .WithUrl("https://localhost:5000/MyHub")
        .Build();  
}
```

Comment: Hi Harshitha and thanks for your suggestion. I tried this already, also where i just hardcoded the local url in the hub connection builder, but it still connects to the web api hosted in azure. And of course also the local running web api.

Comment: Hi @duta, if the description is correct, it's useful for us cheking the azure signalr service metrics  on azure portal. It should be 2 client connections.  If there are 2 client connections, it should be the code issue in your winform application. We should double check the code to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

> when I run the Web API locally, and I try to connect my client, then the client app somehow gets connected to both the locally running Web API AND the Web API hosted in Azure.

Your local and prod web apps connect to Azure SignalR with the same Hub name, all the connected app servers are considered to be instances of the same application which cause the issue.

To fix the issue, you can try to specify `ApplicationName` option, like below.

```
opt.ApplicationName = $"{AppName}_{EnvName}"
```

For more details, please check this doc: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/blob/dev/docs/run-asp-net-core.md#applicationname